# different roles for the same user to different fields/columns of the same table in sql

Tags: sql

I would like to give a user SELECT access to a whole table but UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE to only part of the table.  The table has flag set up to ID which data set the user can change.  For example, an engineer can view the data for all the wells in the company but he can only change the data of the wells that he is responsible for.  Those wells would have a flag such as engineer flag = A.  Another engineer would have engineer flag = B.  engineer A can select wells with the B engineer flag but he can only change the data of the wells with the A flag.

All the research I have done only show how to set it up to have access to the whole table or none of it.  Others have suggested splitting to various table but there is a strong desire to keep the table together so that we can change the flag easier than having to export the data from 1 table to another.

I appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done one of two ways:

- From within the code of the program you're implementing the database, which will validate the association between the engineer and the well; or
- From an `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` function inside the SQL Server, which will receive as a parameter the engineer's ID and the well he's trying to access.

For this to work, every well must be associated to the engineer and the privileges assigned to him to access, update, delete or insert the information.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger for each of those actions, update, insert, and delete. Inside each trigger you can easily determine if it should be allowed or not depending on who it is.